# HTML div-aligning

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website in HTML and CSS. For the footer I would like to have 2 boxes for "contact" and "address" aligned, with the contact-box having 25% width and the addressbox having the rest. Somehow my divs won't line up correctly, the address-box won't vertically align with the top.

My attmept:

```css
.footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.anschrift {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.kontakt {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="anschrift">
    <h2>
      Anschrift:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="kontakt">
    <h2>
      Kontakt:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @fen1x Please see the updated question; we had a concurrent edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.anschrift {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.kontakt {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="anschrift">
    <h2>
      Anschrift:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="kontakt">
    <h2>
      Kontakt:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove the margin left and float the div to right in `.kontakt` i.e change the code of `.kontakt` to

```
.kontakt {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's the margin-left of the contact block, which makes the block bigger than you want it to be. Just remove the margin (or make it smaller).

```css
.footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.anschrift {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.kontakt {
  width: 70%;
  //margin-left: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="anschrift">
    <h2>
      Anschrift:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="kontakt">
    <h2>
      Kontakt:
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.kontakt:margin-left: 28%;` forces a line break as 25%+28%+70% is more than 100%

Answer (score 0):

Actually, If you use the margin in your blocks then you have to reduce same amount width from others blocks/ html div.

So i prefer to **use padding instead of margi**n to make the spacing between the two of multiple column and you have to use **box-sizing** while using the padding.

```
box-sizing:border-box
```